# EntityNotFoundException in Hibernate Many To One mapping however data exist

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I am getting javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException error when I am trying to get User through Invoice object

invoice.getUser().getId()

### Error is as follows

```
javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException: Unable to find com.indianretailshop.domain.User with id 5
    at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration$Ejb3EntityNotFoundDelegate.handleEntityNotFound(Ejb3Configuration.java:137)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.checkTargetState(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:189)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:178)
    at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:215)
```

### Entity classes are as follows(getters and setters are not included)

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;

    .
        .
        .

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Invoice
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Invoice> invoices;
}

@Entity
@Table(name="invoice")
public class Invoice implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(unique=true, nullable=false)
    private int id;
        .
        .
        .

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="Users_id")
    private User user;
}
```

Comment: To get an answer you need to provide some more information, for example: what exactly do you do?, complete stacktrace... And double check that the entity really exists in the database.

Comment: Do you have foreign keys defined from your invoice table to the user table? As @Ralph stated, you should check that the given user (with id 5) actually exists.

Comment: It was working when I was using LAZY fetch, and yes there are entity in database.
I dont understand why it is not working in EAGER fetch, rest of the code is same as before. For now I am using LAZY fetch as temporary change to resolve the issue.

Comment: I have never defined the id using setid() method which means it is getting the id from database only and their is a foreign key exist in database. Is it a bug in hibernate

Comment: And I also noticed if I create two invoices in database then even EAGAR fetch is working so the issue is only seems to exist with exactly one invoice record for one user.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234549/javax-persistence-entitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-entity-with-id

Comment: In my case the problem was a missing CascadeType.ALL in the chain. This was hard to debug since the error was unrelated to that.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

The problem could be that the direct entity does not exist, but also it could be that the referenced entity from that entity, normally for a EAGER fetch type, or optional=false.

Try this:

```
     //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
     @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
     @JoinColumn(name="Users_id")
     private User user = new User();
```

Comment: Earlier I was using LAZY fetch only then it was working and it is not working in EAGER fetch which I don't understand.

Comment: Is this a bug or something which I should report.

Comment: @kakawat 
I have same problem as above, but the code is not in our control,

I have deleted some rows in the database, does improper data cause this kind of error

Comment: I need it to be @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER) and @JsonIgnore

Comment: The Lazy fetch just ends up kicking the error can down the road as when you try to lead the thing that would have been eager fetched you end up with a LazyLoadException. I wish I could understand why it fails to begin with. I am running Hibernate 5.0.11 in Spring Boot 1.5.1

Comment: I am facing the same problem and FetchType.Lazy doesn't solve my problem. In my case the relationship is not bidirectional and I only have the @ManyToOne declared. I am using java-ee-api-7.0.jar for the JPA and not Hibernate. Only if I give NotFoundannotation  the exception does not occur. Any idea what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: In my case I had forgotten to remove @Notnull from the field which was causing this problem.

Comment: This worked for me but i still dont understand why. Someone can help?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73234549/javax-persistence-entitynotfoundexception-unable-to-find-entity-with-id

Answer (score 123):

I had the same problem, and

```
@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
```

solved my problem.

Comment: @dirai I did not try it. NotFound is anyway practical when you don't mind whether the associated entity exists or not.

Comment: The only problem with this is that this fails silently. Has anyone found a better solution that handles this error gracefully while also logging the missing link?

Comment: when using be aware that this causes performance issues! fixing inconsistent data does the job.

Comment: With this, for me, Hibernate is logging:
"13:51:14.466 WARN  [main] o.h.c.AnnotationBinder - HHH000491: The [...] association in the [...] entity uses both @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) and FetchType.LAZY. The NotFoundAction.IGNORE @ ManyToOne and @ OneToOne associations are always fetched eagerly."

Answer (score 48):

If you use @ManyToOne, the referenced entity must exist. The only other option is to specify that field as a long and retrieve the referenced entity by means of a separate query.

Throws an exception (javax.persistence.EntityNotFoundException) instead of returning null if it can't find the requested entity.

Use @NotFound annotation to resolve this exception if you are lazy loading and not handling this exception manually.

```
 @ManyToOne(
        fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @NotFound(
        action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumn(
        name = COLUMN,
        referencedColumnName = COLUMN,
        insertable = false,
        updatable = false)
    private Table table;
```

Answer (score 10):

Not sure if that applies to your case.

But I had a similar issue where I updated directly in the database table X and set a field null, but in java class the field was @NotNull.

So when another class Y had a X object with ManyToOne, it wasn't able to load the entity because of the null value in the entity.

Comment: Thanks, this was my problem. Look for `@NotNull` and `@JoinColumn([...]nullable = false)`.

Comment: @Negal, your comment was de facto the only real explanation to the issue in this thread. The other top rated answers are just workarounds.

Answer (score 7):

please try the following

`@OneToMany(mappedBy="yourMappingattributeName",cascade=CascadeType.ALL)` or

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy="yourMappingattributeName",cascade=CascadeType.MERGE)
```

Answer (score 4):

I had the similar issue recently, but the problem is that record is always existed in DB. So I did some investigation, found out that at some point that cached entity is marked as removal and reload failed before reloading from DB. It happened in `Hibernate 4.3.5` Final for me
Then I upgrade to `Hibernate 4.3.11` Final which seems to fix the issue.

Comment: Simple. Easy. Faster. Great solution!

Answer (score 4):

Use @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE) in case it's parent not exist

By using cascade=CascadeType.ALL it will delete it's parent entity

Comment: I had the same issue with a ManyToOne, lazy loaded. When I added the `@NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)` it resolved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe one comes to this answer and finds it useful: In my case, I have marked my entity as deleted and entity who is relationship with this entity could not find it. So, changing deleted to false worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

It should work when you add `referencedColumnName = COLUMN` in `@JoinColumns` of `@ManyToOne` annotation

Answer (score 0):

You must implement hashCode and equals methods for all entities.
Example:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return Objects.hash(getId());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can now add `optional = true` to the `@ManyToOne` annotation and `nullable = true` to the  `@JoinColumn`. You dont need to swallow the exception. Seems JPA has improved a bit since this question was first posted.

**Example**

```
@ManyToOne(optional = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id", nullable = true)
```

Comment: @Abhijit What error message are you getting?